# Django/Python - Updating the database every second

Tags: python, django

I'm working on creating a browser-based game in Django and Python, and I'm trying to come up with a solution to one of the problems I'm having.

Essentially, every second, multiple user variables need to be updated. For example, there's a currency variable that should increase by some amount every second, progressively getting larger as you level-up and all of that jazz.

I feel like it's a bad idea to do this with cronjobs (and from my research, other people think that too), so right now I'm thinking I should just create a thread that loops through all of the users in the database that performs these updates.

Am I on the right track here, or is there a better solution? In Django, how can I start a thread the second the server starts?

I appreciate the insight.

Comment: Might want to use an asynchronous task framework, i.e. [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: You are quite correct that cron jobs is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @msw What's wrong with using cron jobs?

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions would be to use separate daemonized lightweight python script to perform all the in-game business logic and left django be just the frontend to your game. To bind them together you might pick any of high-performance asynchronous messaging library like ZeroMQ (for instance to pass player's actions to that script). This stack would also have a benefit of a frontend being separated and completely agnostic of a backend implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a better solution would be to not update everyone's currency every second. Instead, store the **timestamp** of the user's most recent transaction, their **income** rate, and their latest **balance**. With these three pieces of data, you can calculate their current balance whenever needed.

When the user makes a purchase for example, do the math to calculate what their new balance is. Some pseudocode:

```
def current_balance(user):
    return user.latest_balance + user.income * (now() - user.last_timestamp)

def purchase(user, price):
    if price > current_balance(user):
        print("You don't have enough cash.")
        return

    user.balance = current_balance(user) - price
    user.last_timestamp = now()
    user.save()
    print("You just bought a thing!")
```

With a system like this, your database will only get updated upon user interaction, which will make your system scale oodles better.