# Django - Update the final result in views.py every n seconds

Tags: python, django, pandas

I built a stock screener that I want to update the final result based on the latest prices during the market hours.
I simplify my original files for better understanding of what I really need.

models.py

```
class ScreenerModel(models.Model)
    pct_choices = [(0, 'all'), (1, 'above 1'), (2, 'below 1')]
    price_choices = [(0, 'all'), (1, 'above 5000'), (2, 'below 5000')]
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    pct = models.IntegerField(choices=pct_choices, default=0)
    price = models.IntegerField(choices=price_choices, default=0)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('users/tmp/<int:pk>/', views.ScreenerModelUser, name='tmp_user'),
]
```

views.py

```
import pandas as pd
from .models import ScreenerModel
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def ScreenerModelUser(request, pk):
    user_screener = ScreenerModel.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id, pk=pk)
    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmirForooghi/stocks_csv/master/stocks_sample.csv')

    pct_user = user_screener.pct
    if pct_user == 1:
        df = df.loc[df.pct > 1]
    if pct_user == 2:
        df = df.loc[df.pct < 1]

    price_user = user_screener.price
    if price_user == 1:
        df = df.loc[df.close > 5000]
    if price_user == 2:
        df = df.loc[df.close < 5000]

    context = {'df': df.to_html()}
    return render(request, 'screener/tmp_user.html', context)
```

tmp_user.html

```
{{ df|safe }}
```

**My Problem**: As you can see I have online prices in the `df` and in the views I just filter them according to the user preference. Obviously the prices change during market hours. I want to update the final result in the template according to the latest prices every n seconds without the user refreshing the page and as long as the URL is open in the browser.

What I have tried so far are listed below:

Add a result field to the models.py to store the final result. and save the result every n seconds in the views.py.

models.py

```
class ScreenerModel(models.Model)
    pct_choices = [(0, 'all'), (1, 'above 1'), (2, 'below 1')]
    price_choices = [(0, 'all'), (1, 'above 5000'), (2, 'below 5000')]
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    pct = models.IntegerField(choices=pct_choices, default=0)
    price = models.IntegerField(choices=price_choices, default=0)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, default='')
```

views.py

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from .models import ScreenerModel
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def ScreenerModelUser(request, pk):
    while True:
        user_screener = ScreenerModel.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id, pk=pk)
        df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AmirForooghi/stocks_csv/master/stocks_sample.csv')

        pct_user = user_screener.pct
        if pct_user == 1:
            df = df.loc[df.pct > 1]
        if pct_user == 2:
            df = df.loc[df.pct < 1]

        price_user = user_screener.price
        if price_user == 1:
            df = df.loc[df.close > 5000]
        if price_user == 2:
            df = df.loc[df.close < 5000]

        user_screener.result = df.to_json()
        user_screener.save()

        context = {'df': df.to_html()}
        return render(request, 'screener/tmp_user.html', context)
        time.sleep(30)
```

And it didn't address the issue. I know in this case javascript and AJAX are needed but I am still learning them right now.

I also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721897/django-python-updating-the-database-every-second) but couldn't solve my problem.

I really appreciate if you can specifically solve this issue or if my entire approach is wrong in doing this, just give a correct approach or even a starting point.

Comment: the code after `return` never executes.

Comment: you can write and API endpoint with django restframe work that you can call with AJAX, that will update the values for you.

Comment: @Mohsan Ali you dont need rest framework for one view which responds on ajax requests :)

Comment: exactly but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. The best choice is to use Javascript and AJAX. The second choice is to use a `<meta>` tag to refresh the page after some interval. It is not desirable but it is easy.

You can read about it @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Basically you are looking for

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/>`